# Microphone not available in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, navigator

I'm trying to check permission of microphone and then start recording using this code, the following code is working on chrome but not working on firefox. It says microphone not available

```
  navigator.permissions.query(
        { name: 'microphone' }
    ).then(permissionStatus => {
        console.log(permissionStatus.state); // granted, denied, prompt
        if(permissionStatus.state != 'granted')
        {  
          alert('Please allow your microphone');
        }
        else
        {
          this.startRecording();
  
        }
        let self=this;
        permissionStatus.onchange = function(){
          if(this.state!='granted')
          {
          }
          else
          {
            self.mic_permission=true;
          }
          console.log("Permission changed to " + this.state);
        } 
    }).catch((error) => {
      //console.log('Got error :', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Permissions API is still experimental. Firefox currently does not support the `microphone` permission [(See here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query).

Use the MediaDevices API [(See here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Build_a_phone_with_peerjs/Connect_peers/Get_microphone_permission) instead:

```html
function getLocalStream() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}).then( stream => {
        window.localStream = stream; // A
        window.localAudio.srcObject = stream; // B
        window.localAudio.autoplay = true; // C
    }).catch( err => {
        console.log("u got an error:" + err)
    });
}
```